# Determine if Server.Transfer[Request] was executed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I was debugging two things and discovered that when an action executed:

```
Server.TransferRequest(url);
return new EmptyResult();
```

that my `Application_Error` would fire and catch the exception "The SessionStateTempDataProvider class requires session state to be enabled."

(I do have session state enabled, specifically StateServer, and for the sake of discussion let's imagine I do not need to commit changes from this request back to the session)

I'd like to control how this scenario gets logged. Obviously I can detect the exception type and message text, but if I wanted to <s>not</s> do special logging when the Request was `.TransferRequest`'d (or `.Transfer`'d), how can I do this?

I have already examined `Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected` - it was `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Server.Transfer will add an unsafe request completion call to the stack, therefore, if there are more than 1 of this, you may think that the request is internally redirected by one of the `Server.Transfer` or `Server.TransferRequest` methods

Here is a boolean function which you can add to your global.asax file, which will return true if it finds more than one instances of request completion frames in the current stack trace.

The `new StackTrace()` is an expensive operation, but, because this is executing in an Exceptional context here, it's overhead "may" be ignored.

```
private bool IsRequestTransferred()
{
    System.Diagnostics.StackTrace stackTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
    int requestCompletionCount = 0;
    foreach (var stackFrame in stackTrace.GetFrames())
    {
        System.Reflection.MethodBase methodBase = stackFrame.GetMethod();
        if (methodBase.DeclaringType.Name == "UnsafeIISMethods" && methodBase.Name == "MgdIndicateCompletion")
        {
            if (++requestCompletionCount == 2)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isRequestTransferred = IsRequestTransferred();
}
```

Comment: This appears to work after I tested a bit (only time in production will tell, eh), but I did need to set the `requestCompletionCount` limit to 4 or higher for us. I don't know why but general errors had a `requestCompletionCount` of 2, and the SessionStateTempDataProvider errors (presumably on a transfer) had 4.

Comment: @Matthew I hope everything ends up fine.

Answer (score 2):

`Server.TransferRequest` accepts headers collection. You can add a special technical header and then look for it later.

```
Server.TransferRequest(url,
    true,
    method: "GET",
    headers: new NameValueCollection() { { "transferred", "true" } });

//and then
bool isTransferred = (Request.Headers["transferred"] != null);
```